# Excel File is corrupted when downloaded from Response Code in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net

I am facing a strange error, i have a code in vb.net which basically just downloads an excel based on the dataset i have created. Everything seems to work fine and the file is downloaded but when i try to open the file, the file is corrupted.

I assume there is a problem in the code or maybe i am missing something, here is the code i am using:

```
   dgGrid.DataSource = DS2.DefaultView   ' This is where i do the Databinding
        dgGrid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = True
        dgGrid.DataBind()

        ExcelFile = name & ".xls"

        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", ExcelFile))
        'Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
        Response.Charset = "utf-8"
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        'Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"  


        dgGrid.RenderControl(htwWriter)
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
        Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble())

        Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"
        Response.Write(style)
        Response.Output.Write(stwWriter.ToString())
        Response.End()
        'Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Response.Close()
        Response.Flush()
        'Response.Write()
        'Response.End()
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated :(

Comment: Yes it is corrupt. You are creating a html page with an xls extension.

Comment: Thanks VDWWD, Can you tell me how can i resolve it?

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example.

Comment: @VDWWD And serving it up with the content type for an XLSX file. Poor computer. I'd be confused too.

Comment: Hi Guys, i really cant use EPPLUS for the downloading, cause that would require me to upload the .dll on PROD BOX which i dont have permission to do as there would be Pen Testing required and the company dont want to do that. So any other way to do it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after flushing the file.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```